# Can I apply what I do to document.getElementById to document.getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("myId").style.left = 100px;
```

Is there a SHORT way to use the code above to a class?

Will the code below work?

```
doucment.getElementsByClassName("myClass").style.left = 100px;
```

What I wanted to do was to move multiple images to the same place and it should be flexible so that it would work if the user wanted 1, 2, 3 or more images to move to that place.

Comment: With a loop, yes. Plural `getElements...` methods will return a collection.

Comment: Use jQuery for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no knowledge on jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object (an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)), so you need to specify the element(s) you want to apply the change to. For example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0].style.left = 100px;
```

Would be applied to the first element with that class. Otherwise you need to loop over the set.

Comment: Is there a shortcut for having it all in that array?

Comment: I mean automatically changing all the styles of all elements in that array? Or do I really have to loop it?

Comment: No, you'll need to loop over the collection in some form, whether  a for loop, filter, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The `getElementsByClassName()` function returns a NodeList, so you'll need to iterate over it and apply the style to each element in turn. That's relatively easy to do using `forEach`, but you need to convert to an Array first:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")).forEach(function(elem,index) {
    elem.style.left = 100px;
});
```

Comment: forEach is not a method of nodeList object, you have to convert it into array.
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")).forEach

Comment: wait wait I'm lost here so where does the Array.prototype.slice....... come in the code above?

Comment: @GuerasArnaud You're right, thanks for pointing that out. I think I was thinking of Dojo when writing the answer.